# Looking for short braided hose -- like faucet hose, but with two big ends

Tags: plumbing, faucet

The 'end' I need is exactly the same as the faucet end of a standard stop-valve-to-faucet hose. The application is to connect a faucet tap to the spout, one hose per side, on a salvaged brass fixture. There is one hose but it's not in good shape.

Problem is, I can't even find a good description of what that end is, because it's standard and nobody selling a faucet hose needs to describe it. Looks like 14TPI and about 0.820" outer diameter on the male threads, so, it's like a 1/2" pipe thread, but without the taper (maybe that's a 1/2" 'hose thread')?

Anyway, I'm not even sure that knowing what the thread is officialy called, will help locate replacement hoses. Any help will be appreciated. Hose should be at least 8" long, and ideally no more than 24".

"Washing machine" hoses are very similar to what I need, but have larger diameter ends (same as garden hose) and are too long.

Picture shows most of the parts, basically complete hot side (except for a brass threaded part that holds the bell-shaped trim down; present but not shown). The cold side is also complete (with other parts not shown) but the valve-to-spout hose is absent.

[image]

Comment: I would like to see a picture of the salvaged brass thing and a schematic of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Willk done! (connection should be clear from the photo).

Comment: I guess one approach is to get four of the shortest faucet supply hoses I can find, and connect the little ends together with male-to-male couplers to make two hoses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your local Home Depot. Lowes. or any large hardware store like Ace and look for what you want on their shelves. You are probably looking for 1/2"fip X 1/2"fip hoses which they should have in stock. If you can't find what you are looking for ask the store clerk that heads that department.I have a similar solid brass faucet that I purchased 20 years ago from a supply store in Pittsburgh, Pa. that connects the same way. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I should be able to do that in a few weeks when we're out of lockdown.